# How to compute rolling dot product/cosine similarity on pandas dataframe with a number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity, rolling-computation

My main objective of this question is to calculate the rolling `dot_product` or `cosine_similarity` over a pandas dataframe. Going through the documentation, I found that, technically we can compute the rolling `correlation` function using the following syntax:

`df.rolling(window_size).corr()`.

However, I am wondering how to compute the rolling `cosine_similarity`. For instance, I would like to have something like:

```
 from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
 df.rolling(window=3, method="table").apply(lambda table: cosine_similarity(table.T))
```

However, this is throwing an error.

---

Kindly note below the entire code to regenerate the same problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from IPython.display import display
pd.__version__   # 1.4.3

def generate_random_walk(_len):
    lst = [np.random.randn()]
    for i in range(_len): 
        lst.append(lst[i] + np.random.randn())
    return lst

_len = 100
_num_arrays = 5

array_2D = np.array([generate_random_walk(_len) for _ in range(_num_arrays)]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(array_2D)

df.rolling(window=3, method="table").apply(lambda table: cosine_similarity(table.T))
```

Please note that I am using:
**Python version: 3.10,**
 and
**Pandas version: 1.4.3**

I would expect the answer to include a solution using pandas native api. Else, any solution avoiding a for loop is great, given how slow the code can get using for loop. I did personally made some comparison on the `corr` function using pandas native functions and using a for loop, and the former was more than 100 times faster. Finally, if no pandas native function is available for the `cosine_similarity`; and if there doesn't exist a solution similar to this: `df.rolling(window=3, method="table").apply(lambda table: cosine_similarity(table.T))` I would appreciate having a solution using a for loop and `numba` for faster computations.

Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my solution, using `numpy` and `numba` for faster processing.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from numba import jit, njit
import numba

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
```

## Explanation

The main objective of this problem is to calculate the rolling `cosine_similarity` over a given matrix. In other words, I would like to achieve a similar behavior to the pandas native function: `df.rolling(window_size).corr()` which return the corrlation coefficient for each sliding window over a given dataframe. More information about the rolling correlation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.corr.html). The following figure demonstrate how the sliding window works over `axis=0`.

[image]

As a result, each window will be passed to the `corr()` function, and the result of `corr()` is a dataframe of size **(N x N)** where **N** is the number of columns in the main dataframe. The output of `df.rolling(window_size).corr()` is roughly: **(len(df) - window_size + 1, N, N )**.

---

In the following sections, I will go over the main steps for caclulating the cosine similarity over a 2D array (to be covered in section 1). Under section 2, I will show the main implementation in python I will be using `numba` to achieve faster processing times. Finally, I will apply the `cos_similarity` over a sliding window as shown in the figure above.

### Section 1

The formula for cosine similarity is:

[image]

Therefore, if we have a given matrix **A** with **m** number of rows and **N** number of columns, calculating the cosine similarity between each and every col requires us to go through a nested for loop, consuming every pair of columns, and then apply the cosine formula above. A python code snippet will look like this:

```py
def calc_cosine_sim(a, b):
    dot_product = a*b
    a_norm = np.linalg.norm(a)
    b_norm = np.linalg.norm(b)
    return dot_product / (a_norm * b_norm)

A = np.array(some_values)     # A.shape = (m, N)

lst = []
for i in range(N - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        lst.append(cal_cosine_sim(A[:, i], A[:, j]))
```

Given that we are calculating the dot product between each and every pair of columns, the same process can be achieved using a matrix multiplication. In other words, if we take the transpose of **A** and multiply it with itself we should get another matrix who's entries reflect the dot product of **A**'s columns.

Assume we have the following matrix:

[image]

Where each row represent one instance, and each col represent a feature, or a vector. Likewise, we will assume:

[image]

Multiplying the transpose of A with itself will produce:

[image]

Consequently, using matrix multiplication, I have achieved the same result without using for loops. This process is much faster due to vectorization in numpy.

However, the cosine similarity requires us dividing the vector dot product by the norms of both vectors. Therefore, we would love to get this matrix:

[image]

However, this is simply:

[image]

However,

[image]

Therefore, if we simply calculate the norms **|a|**, **|b|** and **|c|**, and then create the above 2 matrices (**B** and **C**), that should enable us to calculate the **norm_matrix**, which when multiplied by **A^{T}.A** will return the final result, **cosine_similarity* matrix. In the next section, I will go through the python code to explain how the theory above gets translated into code.

One final note: **C = B^{T}**. Therefore, we should only produce **B**, and what will be used to generate **C**.

### Section 2

Below is the python implementation using numpy. This is a straight forward implementation, without using numba. I have added comments to reflects the steps and matrices generated above, in section 1. Below I have written 2 methods: `calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v1` and `calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v2` on purpose so that I use both the `cosine_similarity` implementation from sklearn and my implementation in numpy. The aim is to compare the numbers at the end and make sure the implementation is correct

```
# This is the implementation of the above logic (section 1) using numpy library
def calc_cosine_similarity_on_2darray(arr):
    '''
    Input is 2D array
    Return the cosine similarity matrix over the 2D array. In other words, the result is the cosine similarity between
    each and every column of the input 2Darray/matrix.
    '''
    # Equation 1
    arr_x_arr = arr.T @ arr

    # Calculating Matrix B
    arr_norm = np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=0)
    arr_norm_r = np.expand_dims(arr_norm, axis=0)
    arr_norm_r_m = np.tile(arr_norm_r, (arr_norm_r.shape[1], 1))

    # Calculating Matrix C
    arr_norm_c_m = arr_norm_r_m.T
    # Calculating Matrix norm_matrix
    arr_norm_mul = arr_norm_r_m * arr_norm_c_m

    # return matrix: cosine_similarity
    return arr_x_arr / arr_norm_mul

# This funtion will calculate the rolling cosine similarity using simply the sliding_window_view numpy function and 
# cosine_similarity from the sklearn library
def calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v1(array, window_size, num_features):
    array_2D_windowed = np.squeeze(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(array_2D, 
                                                                            window_shape=(window_size, num_features)))
    # arr is transposed on purpose because the cosine_similarity from sklearn will compute cos_sim between the matrix rows.
    # Therefore, the transpose will put the features, aka columns, in the first dimension.
    cos_sim = [cosine_similarity(arr.T) for arr in array_2D_windowed]
    return cos_sim

def calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v2(array, window_size, num_features):
    array_2D_windowed = np.squeeze(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(array_2D, 
                                                                            window_shape=(window_size, num_features)))
    cos_sim = [calc_cosine_similarity_on_2darray(arr) for arr in array_2D_windowed]
    return cos_sim
```

The same implementation modified to use `numba` package in python to speed up our computations. the following numpy functions generated some errors if used with numba:

- `np.linalg.norm`
- `np.expand_dims`
- `np.tile`

Finally, I could have implemented manually the numpy function `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`. I am not sure how faster this method could be when used with `numba`. I left this one on purpose due to my time constraints.

```
# this function returns the norm of a vector v.
@njit
def calc_norm(v):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(v)))

# The implementation here is equivalent to the implementation of calc_cosine_similarity_on_2darray above
# but modified to utilize the numba python package for faster processing.
@njit
def calc_cosine_similarity_on_2darray_numba(arr):
    '''
    Input is 2D array
    Return the similarity matrix over the 2D array. In other words, the result is the cosine similarity between
    each and every column of the input 2Darray/matrix.
    '''
    # Equation 1
    arr_x_arr = arr.T @ arr

    # Calculating Matrix B
    arr_norm_r = np.zeros(shape=(1, arr.shape[1]))
    for i in range(arr.shape[1]):                    # iterate over each col in arr
        arr_norm_r[0, i] = calc_norm(arr[:, i])      # calculate the norm of every col in arr.
    arr_norm_r_m = np.ones(shape=(arr.shape[1], arr.shape[1])) * arr_norm_r

    # Calculating Matrix C
    arr_norm_c_m = arr_norm_r_m.T

    # Calculating Matrix norm_matrix
    arr_norm_mul = arr_norm_r_m * arr_norm_c_m

    # return matrix: cosine_similarity
    return arr_x_arr / arr_norm_mul

@njit
def rolling_cosine_similarity_numba(array_windowed):
    cos_sim = [calc_cosine_similarity_on_2darray_numba(arr) for arr in array_windowed]
    return cos_sim

def calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_numba(arr, window_size, num_features):
    array_windowed = np.squeeze(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, window_shape=(window_size, num_features)))
    cos_sim = rolling_cosine_similarity_numba(array_windowed)
    return cos_sim

# Helper function to generate random signal.
def generate_random_walk(_len):
    lst = [np.random.randn()]
    for i in range(_len - 1): 
        lst.append(lst[i] + np.random.randn())
    return lst

signal_len = 24*365*5
num_features = 5
window_size = 10

array_2D = np.array([generate_random_walk(signal_len) for _ in range(num_features)]).T
array_2D.shape
```

--> output: (43800, 5)

```
%%timeit

calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v1(array_2D, window_size, num_features)
```

--> output: 9.87 s ± 127 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%%timeit

calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v2(array_2D, window_size, num_features)
```

--> output: 2.79 s ± 100 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%%timeit

calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_numba(array_2D, window_size, num_features)
```

--> output: 343 ms ± 4.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
sol1 = np.array(calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v1(array_2D, window_size, num_features))
sol2 = np.array(calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_v2(array_2D, window_size, num_features))
sol3 = np.array(calc_rolling_cosine_similarity_numba(array_2D, window_size, num_features))

sol1.shape, sol2.shape, sol3.shape
```

--> output: ((43791, 5, 5), (43791, 5, 5), (43791, 5, 5))

```
np.allclose(sol1, sol2), np.allclose(sol2, sol3), np.allclose(sol1, sol3)
```

--> output: (True, True, True)

### Conclusion

The same solution, when using `numba` is almost **9.87 / 0.343 ~ 30** times faster than the native sklearn implementation, and **2.79 / 0.343 ~ 8** times faster than the same numpy implementation without numba.